# Prove that the set of nonnegative numbers is denumerable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computer-science

> > I need to show through a proof that the set of nonnegative numbers is *denumerable*

I know a set is ***denumerable*** if its members or elements can be put into an order and counted. I am supposed to show this through a proof as well.
I was considering using *Induction* possibly but I'm not sure if this is a viable or feasible method to use. **Any help is great appreciated**

Comment: You must mean *nonnegative* ***integer*** *numbers*.

Comment: I do, we can call this the set of all natural numbers or positive integers.

Comment: Not quite.  The positive integers = natural numbers do not contain 0 but the non-negatives do.  Denumerable means can be put in 1-1 corespondence with the naturals.  Trivially the natural numbers can be put in 1-1 corespondence with themselves.  This is asking how do you add an extra element, namely 0, and put the set into 1-1 corespondence.

Answer (score 2):

The set of non-negative numbers: I assume you talk of non-negative integers. 
The set would be $\{0,1,2,3...\}$.

Every element of the set can be associated with a natural number as $n-1$ where $n$ is the natural number.

That means: $0$ is associated with $1$, $1$ is associated with $2$ and so on. When every element of the given set can be associated with a natural number, It is denumerable (countably infinite).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* – Your set is $A=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. How would you proceed, using this?

Answer (score 0):

Every subset of a denumerable set is either denumerable or finite. In particular , your set is an infinite subset of set of all integers and hence denumerable.

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you already know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is denumerable.